# Exclude AnsibleUndefined from a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Relevant part of task:

```yaml
- name: Get join-token for worker nodes
  set_fact:
    join_token_worker: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map('extract', hostvars, ['result', 'swarm_facts', 'JoinTokens', 'Worker']) }}"
  run_once: true

- debug:
    msg: "{{ join_token_worker }}"
  run_once: true
```

And the output looks like this:

```
TASK [deploy_docker : Get join-token for worker nodes] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [eu-central-1a-01]

TASK [deploy_docker : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [eu-central-1a-01] => {
    "msg": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, 'SWMTKN-1-2xgm1l987hh18gbq0tc8vrwn209qlxge6nkwdq4pof2zd4e2vs-7f7ig2ama5amqq8iuii4o8xxo', AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, 'SWMTKN-1-2xgm1l987hh18gbq0tc8vrwn209qlxge6nkwdq4pof2zd4e2vs-7f7ig2ama5amqq8iuii4o8xxo', AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"
}
```

I want to extract the token from this list - but I don't know how to filter out `AnsibleUndefined` value. I am using [docker_swarm](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docker_swarm_module.html) module to get `result`.

Comment: [`| select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) alleges it will include only truthy items, so try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's minimize the case. For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: h1,h2,h3
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    d2:
      h1:
        k1:
          k2: v1
      h2:
        k1:
          kX: v2
      h3:
        k1:
          k2: v3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', d2, ['k1', 'k2'])|
                 list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '[''v1'', Undefined, ''v3'']'
```

There are more options for how to **"*Exclude AnsibleUndefined from a list*"**.

1. Use *select* (credit @mdaniel)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', d2, ['k1', 'k2'])|
                 select|
                 list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - v1
  - v3
```

2. Use *regex_replace*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', d2, ['k1', 'k2'])|
                 map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\1')|
                 list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - v1
  - ''
  - v3
```

3. If you want to create a dictionary iterate the hosts. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        worker_dict: "{{ worker_dict|default({})|
                         combine({item: d2[item].k1.k2|default('')}) }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  worker_dict:
    h1: v1
    h2: ''
    h3: v3
```

Comment: i have tested the above on my scenario but getting errors. My list look like this 

    test_list:
      - name: paul
        number: 1
        id: 65
      - name: john
        number: 2
      - name: ringo
        number: 3
        id: 67

any idea how to work around this using Jinja?
I need to get 'id' values from this list

my solution so far is:

    - name: get ids
      set_fact:
        ids: "{{ ids | default([]) +  [ item.id | default('') ] }}"
      loop: "{{ test_list }}"